# PHP code doesn't work anymore after SQL version update by my provider?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have an http-bridge to exchange information between a Second Life application and a database. It was working fine but stopped recently after my provider changed the SQL version of my database to **5.5.38**. Here is an example of my old php script:

```html
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("DB_HOSTNAME","DB_USERNAME","DB_PASSWORD", "DB_DATABASE");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$PKey = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['playerKey']);
$HKey = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['hudKey']);  

echo $HKey, " and " , $PKey;

$sql="INSERT INTO test (HKey, PKey)
VALUES ('$HKey', '$PKey')";

echo $sql . '<br/>'; 

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I get the following error message:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-get (HKey, PKey) VALUES ('XXXXXXX-fe56-XXXX-4bea-XXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXX' at line 1

I have tried to use this insert statement which I found in a post on Stack Overflow:

```html
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (HKey, PKey) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $HKey, $PKey);
$stmt->execute();
```

But when I insert that line of code, it doesn't work either and I don't get any error message at all.

Comment: `$P-Key` and `$H-Key` don't use hyphens. `(H-Key, P-Key)` same thing here. Use ticks `\`` around the columns. SQL is interpreting that as "H **minus** Key" etc. for both instances. It's not your provider, it's your code.

Comment: echo $H-Key, " and " , $P-Key; is still incorrect use $PKey and $HKey

Comment: `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare` you're using `$con` as DB connection variable.

Comment: Also make sure your form is method GET and not POST. You should be posting that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to post the strings that I am actually using, so I just made them up. Now I created additional confusion...I changed it into an acceptable format.

Comment: `right syntax to use near '-get (HKey, PKey)` what you posted will NOT throw that error. Why don't you start over and post the code you're really using, along with the form and how you are passing the inputs with a real example. What I think it *really* is, your table name contains a hyphen, which again and as my original comment. SQL thinks you want to do math.

Comment: Hi Fred, you are really good at guessing. my table name does contain a hyphen. Will test that and then edit the question.

Comment: why don't you just try it

Comment: *"Hi Fred, you are really good at guessing. my table name does contain a hyphen."* - I wasn't guessing. The error told me `right syntax to use near '-get (HKey, PKey)` ;-) If you're going to use that name, wrap the table name in ticks `\`` <= or rename it so that it's an underscore. I.e.: `table_get`

Comment: I can't see the code you are using, as Fred says, and I can't see how it has ever worked. It should have blown up on the previous MySQL server version too. As it stands, this question will close, but at least the lesson is valuable - show the real code, not a sanitised version of it.

Comment: @halfer I think the OP's present moment of silence can be interpreted as: *"Woohoo, it works and I'm having so much fun with this!!"* ;-)

Comment: Hopefully! To be fair, I don't think I've seen this _specific_ problem on SO before, so it's good to get a Q&A on it.

Comment: @halfer You mean, having an specific error based on what OP posts, but is not actual code? I've seen it quite a few times lol. The error message was obvious. OP thinks I guessed it; *nope*. As I am sure you also deducted ;-)

Comment: OP, I've moved your update to an answer (it overwrote a number of improvement edits I made to your question, so it needed rolling back anyway - see the edit history). Also, oh dear!, please do not type entirely in upper case anywhere on the internet - it is commonly regarded as shouting. This is not a Stack Overflow rule - it is netiquette from the last 25 years or so.

Comment: I feel kind of silly to have started such a huge discussion with incorrect posting. I just added this to my post (now edited so that no one can mistake it for shouting): Ok, the error was not on the side of my service provider, but me working with a new table that contained a hyphan. This was my first post and I made the mistake to confuse everyone by not publishing 100% original code. I have learned my lessan and won't do that again. Sorry for everyone that feels that they wasted their time. It has helped me anyway sorting out the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`right syntax to use near '-get (HKey, PKey)`

What you posted `vvv` will **NOT** throw that error.

```
INSERT INTO test (HKey, PKey)
```

> *"Hi Fred, you are really good at guessing. my table name does contain a hyphen."*

Your table name contains a hyphen. (*and I wasn't guessing, the error told me*)

How was I able to tell?

- *It's clear.* The column names that you have HKey and PKey, and seeing the `-get` just before the column names in the error your posted.
- Syntax: `INSERT INTO table (column_1, column_2) VALUES ('value_1', 'value_2')`
- table = your table-get, column_1 = your HKey, and column_2 = your PKey

If your table is called "table-get" for example, then MySQL is interpreting that as "table **minus** get".

Either you use backticks around the table name, or rename it to "table_get" using an underscore.

I.e.:

```
INSERT INTO `table-get` (HKey, PKey)
```

or rename it without the use of ticks (if it doesn't contain a space or reserved word)

```
INSERT INTO table_get (HKey, PKey)
```

Read up on Identifier Qualifiers:

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html**

Plus, as Halfer stated in a comment:

*"I can't see the code you are using, as Fred says, and I can't see how it has ever worked. It should have blown up on the previous MySQL server version too."*

- Which I agree with also.

---

*Tip on posting a question:*

Whenever posting a question and do not want to post actual code for some reason or another, at least post a good representation of it.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO test-get (HKey, PKey)
```

At least everyone will be able to tell by pseudo-code, where the error could be.

- It makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted answer on behalf of OP).*

Ok, the error was not on the side of my service provider, but me working with a new table that contained a hyphan. This was my first post and I made the mistake to confuse everyone by not publishing 100% original code. I have learned my lessan and won't do that again. Sorry for everyone that feels that they wasted their time. It has helped me anyway sorting out the errors.

Comment: Couldn't you have un-all-capsed the answer before reposting it...?

Comment: Hey you guys are just too fast for me. I cleaned it up now.   ;)

Comment: @Pienaar You accepted the wrong answer. Look at the one I posted.

Comment: @Fred: I guess I have now made every single mistake that was possible... Well, thanks to pointing me to the corrections.

Comment: @Pienaar: it's OK. Whilst it is acceptable to accept/tick a "community wiki" post, there is not much value in doing so, since no-one gets the reputation points. If I answer on behalf of someone else I tend to use CW, which says to people "it's not my post, no need to tick/upvote". There are quite a lot of memes to learn here, but stick around - you'll get the hang of it!

Comment: @Pienaar You're welcome. I have a lot of patience; I grow cactus (really) ;-)